# Display div element from selected row in gridview in label

Tags: asp.net, gridview, row

I have written a code to display selected row in the form having labels and most of the data in the gridview are stored in labels but one cell is storing data in div element . So, the question is how to fetch that data in the div element and display it in the label.

This is my aspx code of gridview

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOC PATH" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <div id="DIV1" style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
                    <%#Eval("[DOC PATH]") %>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

THis is my code behind

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    lblTASKIDOUTPUT.Text = (row.FindControl("TASKID") as Label).Text;
    lblDescOutput.Text = (row.FindControl("DESC") as Label).Text;
    lblFrequencyOutput.Text = (row.FindControl("FREQUENCY") as Label).Text;
    lblDocPathOutput.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
}
```

The above three lblTASKIDOUTPUT,DescOutput and FrequencyOutput are all working because they have been kept in labels in the template fields in grid view . But, the problem is with the 4th one the doc path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use literal control here. Instead of displaying the text directly under div, use Literal control, which does not render any html tag.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOC PATH" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <div id="DIV1" style="width: 100px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis">
              <asp:Literal ID="literalPath" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[DOC PATH]") %>'></asp:Literal>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

You can then access the literal control as below

```
Literal literalPath= row.FindControl("literalPath") as Literal;
```

This you can use it further